# Its dataset "faithful" preloaded by default in any LIBRARY?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

When I write and run the following code, everything is done fine, but I have a doubt if someone could confirm it for me:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from scipy import stats 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
from pydataset import data

sns.set_palette("deep", desat=.6)
sns.set_context(rc={"figure.figsize": (8, 4)})

faithful = data('faithful')
faithful.head(10)
```

All works fine. But, in the penultimate row above, the dataset 'faithful' I have not loaded, no copied, no have I linked to a URL to access said data. However, it runs and reads all the data. I must assume that this DataSet is included by default, in some library? Which one ?. Where is it located? How can I corroborate or verify this information? Any command? Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the built-in datasets from **pydataset** module when you are running your 7th line:
**from pydataset import data**

If you run **data()** command, you will see all the 750+ datasets contained in this module. 'faithful' data is also present in this.